# uploading a custom app: the link doesn't appear

Tags: microsoft-teams

The link to upload custom apps just doesn't appear. We have set all the settings in the ms teams app itself (team's configuration) and in admin.teams.microsoft.com. We are the team owner and the global owner, but the link just doesn't appear.

What am I missing and how can this be real?

Thank

Comment: Could you please check if you have [sideloading enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/prepare-your-o365-tenant) for your tenant?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HswxZ.png